# Setting a transparent background with three.js

Tags: javascript, css, animation, three.js

This is my first time working with three.js,

I found a codepen that I really like, but I'm having troubles changing the background colour.

I've taken a look at other questions asked on this topic, and tried adding `{ alpha: true}`
to the `renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();` as this post suggests: [Transparent background with three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495302/transparent-background-with-three-js)

My goal is to create a transparent background on the `<div class="page-content"></div>` element.. I would really appreciate any help!

The codepen: https://codepen.io/ramsaylanier/pen/raybzy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are a couple things missing there:

1. You do need `alpha: true` on the scene, as you mention.
2. Don't change `setClearColor`.
3. If you're using EffectComposer, there is some extra work required to make it allow a transparent background, see these comments. [How do I stop EffectComposer from destroying my transparent background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899326/how-do-i-stop-effectcomposer-from-destroying-my-transparent-background)

I'd recommend starting with `renderer.render( scene, camera )` instead of `composer.render()` just to make sure you have the first two parts working.

Answer (score 0):

new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
canvas: canvas,

```
 preserveDrawingBuffer: true,  // so canvas.toBlob() make sense

alpha:true,   // so png background is transparent
```

})

Answer (score 0):

If it still doesn't work after doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65856532/16938897), make sure you are not changing the background of the scene!