# Three.js Transparent Background

Tags: javascript, css, three.js

I know this might sound repeated, I googled it and found answers here about the background color such as this link ([Transparent background with three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495302/transparent-background-with-three-js)), But that solution and some others did not work for my case.

I forked a codepen creation from someone else, and tried to adapt it to use it dynamically but I'm unable to remove the background even when setting `alpha: true`, `setClearColor` and `scene.background = null` into Scene instance.

I'm new in Three.js and I could not find the actual solution to my problem I've decided to post.

I tried debugging the camera angles thinking that might be the issue? - Still unsuccesful.

Here's a Codepen link so you can check it out (it starts at Line 141)

https://codepen.io/ig10/pen/JjLJNyX

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It should be just this:

```js
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } );
```

Comment: Yeah I have that still doesn't work in my case specifically.

```
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: false,
  alpha: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65856532/4358866) suggests, the issue is with the composer.
When I switch the `composer.render()` with `renderer.render(scene, camera)` I see the red background

So this is probably the correct duplicate:
[How do I stop EffectComposer from destroying my transparent background?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20899326/4358866)

Comment: Seems like this could be the issue, I tried adding target to the composer and everything but nope. I might have to consider another way I believe :s. Thank you for ur response.