# Making canvas background transparent

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas

Here is my HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT (THREE.JS) code.
Can you please analyze the code and check for my desired output that i put in my title.

```
//**HTMLCODE**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/index.css" />
    <script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@v0.150.1/build/three.module.js",
          "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@v0.150.1/examples/jsm/"
        }
      }
    </script>
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>EXAMPLE</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div class="globe-render" id="globe-render">
      <script type="module" src="./globe.js"></script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

**//CSS CODE:**

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
body {
  background-color: #000f14;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New",
    monospace;
}

#globe-render {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20%;
  left: 20%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
#myCanvas {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
}


//JS CODE
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import { EffectComposer } from "three/addons/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js";
import { RenderPass } from "three/addons/postprocessing/RenderPass.js";
import { UnrealBloomPass } from "three/addons/postprocessing/UnrealBloomPass.js";

//Radius define
let ParticleSurfaceLayer = 7.5;
let GlobeRadius = 6.6;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
const container = document.querySelector(".globe-render");
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000,0);
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


// Group for globe and particle system
const group = new THREE.Group();
scene.add(group);

// Bloom pass for the globe
const renderScene = new RenderPass(scene, camera);
const globeBloomPass = new UnrealBloomPass(
  new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight),
  1.5,
  0.4,
  0.85
);
globeBloomPass.threshold = 0;
globeBloomPass.strength = 2;
globeBloomPass.radius = 0;

const globeComposer = new EffectComposer(renderer);
globeComposer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
globeComposer.addPass(renderScene);
globeComposer.addPass(globeBloomPass);

// Bloom pass for particles
const particleComposer = new EffectComposer(renderer);
particleComposer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
particleComposer.addPass(new RenderPass(group, camera)); // Assuming 'group' contains particles
const particleBloomPass = new UnrealBloomPass(
  new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight),
  1.5,
  0.4,
  0.85
);

particleBloomPass.threshold = 0;
particleBloomPass.strength = 1.3;
particleBloomPass.radius = 0.8;
particleComposer.addPass(particleBloomPass);

// Update size function
function updateSize() {
  const newWidth = window.innerWidth;
  const newHeight = window.innerHeight;

  camera.aspect = newWidth / newHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(newWidth, newHeight);

  const sphereRadius = Math.min(newWidth, newHeight) * 0.1;
  globe.geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(sphereRadius, 32, 32);

  const particleSizeMin = Math.min(newWidth, newHeight) * 0.001;
  const particleSizeMax = Math.min(newWidth, newHeight) * 0.004;

  group.children.forEach((particle) => {
    const randomSize = THREE.MathUtils.randFloat(
      particleSizeMin,
      particleSizeMax
    );
    particle.scale.set(randomSize, randomSize, randomSize);
  });

  // Update composer sizes
  globeComposer.setSize(newWidth, newHeight);
  particleComposer.setSize(newWidth, newHeight);
}

//orbit controls
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
controls.enableZoom = false;
// controls.enabled=false

// Initial setup
////////
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(GlobeRadius, 80, 80);
const material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: loader.load("./8k_earth_nightmap_underlayer.jpg"),
  //transparent: true,
  opacity: 1,
});
const material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xff047e,
  transparent: true,
  opacity: 0.1,
});
const multimaterial = [material1, material2];
const globe = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material1);
globe.layers.set(1);
group.add(globe);

// Particle System
const particleCount = 600;
const color = new THREE.Color("#fc2414");

for (let i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) {
  // ... (same as your code)

  const phi = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
  const theta = Math.random() * Math.PI - Math.PI / 2;
  const randomradius = 0.01 + Math.random() * 0.04;

  const radius = ParticleSurfaceLayer; // Radius of the sphere

  const x = radius * Math.cos(theta) * Math.cos(phi);
  const y = radius * Math.cos(theta) * Math.sin(phi);
  const z = radius * Math.sin(theta);

  const particleGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(randomradius, 30, 25); // Initial size
  const particleMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: "#00FFFF",
  });
  const particle = new THREE.Mesh(particleGeometry, particleMaterial);

  particle.position.set(x, y, z);
  particle.layers.set(1);
  group.add(particle);
}

const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 100);
scene.add(ambientLight);

// Camera position
camera.position.z = 15;

// Rotation animation
const rotationSpeed = 0.001;

// Animation function
const animate = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  group.rotation.y += rotationSpeed;

  // Render globe with bloom effect
  camera.layers.set(1);
  globeComposer.render();

  // Render particles with bloom effect
  particleComposer.render();
};
///////orbit controls///*
let isDragging = false;
let originalRotation = group.rotation.y;

// Event listener for mouse down
renderer.domElement.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
  isDragging = true;
});

// Event listener for mouse up
renderer.domElement.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  isDragging = false;
  // Reset the rotation to its original position
  group.rotation.y = originalRotation;
});

// Event listener for mouse leave (in case mouse leaves the canvas while dragging)
renderer.domElement.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  if (isDragging) {
    isDragging = false;
    // Reset the rotation to its original position
    group.rotation.y = originalRotation;
  }
});

// Handle window resize
window.addEventListener("resize", updateSize);

// Start animation
animate();

const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
canvas.id = "myCanvas";
canvas.classList.add("myCanvasClass");
```

[image: Screen Shot of my rendered page]

I tried setClearColor in js, transparent in the css block for canvas.
I want the canvas convert from black background to transparent. Please some one help this.

Comment: "( I don't know what to write of 220 characters minimum so i typing this, please neglect this braced content)" [250+ lines of code follow...]. Please thoroughly describe the code, the problem, and your attempts at solving it. Are you sure [all of the code you posted is necessary to reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you see [Changing three.js background to transparent or other color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177056/changing-three-js-background-to-transparent-or-other-color) and [Transparent background with three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495302/transparent-background-with-three-js)? If not, please take a look at try using them to solve your problem. If you did, please show that you tried all of the answers there and describe how they didn't work for you. Thanks.

Comment: i did here:
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
const container = document.querySelector(".globe-render");
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000,0);

Comment: Thanks for confirming. You might want to [edit] your question to link to the posts then and say that it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it could be problem with passes which are you using. If you remove these passes it still doesn't work? Because some passes could have problem with transparency.
Try set webgl target and add RGBA format, it should help with problem. There is sample code, which should help with transparency.

```
const canvas = this.renderer.domElement;
const width = canvas.clientWidth * this.pixelRatio | 0;
const height = canvas.clientHeight * this.pixelRatio | 0;
const parameters = { minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, format: THREE.RGBAFormat, stencilBuffer: false };
const renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(width, height, parameters);
renderTarget.texture.encoding = QUnityCore.instance.renderManager.renderer.outputEncoding
const composer = new EffectComposer(this.renderer, renderTarget);
composer.renderToScreen = false;
```

Or you can find more info in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899326/how-do-i-stop-effectcomposer-from-destroying-my-transparent-background). I hope this will help you.